# Stata: Estimation of Own-Price and Cross-Price Elasticities for Logit, Nested Logit, and BLP Models

Tags: econometrics, stata, panel-data

I am working with some data on automobile sales and characteristics in a small country. It is an unbalanced panel dataset taken over 6 years and over 5 market segments. 
I am trying to construct some discrete-choice demand models using Stata, using two OLS models (one where Price comes in linearly, one where Price is logged) and a nested logit. I will do my BLP instruments model next.

The OLS models are: 
δj=ln P(j)-ln P(0)=βxj-αpj+εj

and

δj=ln P(j)-ln P(0)=βxj-αln(pj)+εj

The nested logit is as follows:

δj=ln P(j)-ln P(0)=βxj-αpj+σ[ln P(j)- ln P(g)]+ξj  for j∈g.

Where P(j) and P(0) represent, respectively, the probability of buying good j and the probability of buying an outside good. Xj is a vector of the characteristics of each good j (in this case, I am using CC/weight, Maximum Speed/100 and Size = Length*Width/10000), and pj is the price of good j.

The code I have used to define my variables and then runmy regressions is as follows:

```
    gen lnPj=ln(Sj)
    gen lnPg=ln(Sg1)
    gen deltaj=ln(Sj/S0)
    gen MSP100=0.01*MSpeed
    gen LW10000= Length*Width*.0001
    gen diffPjPg= lnPj-lnPg
    reg deltaj CCW MSP100 LW10 P, robust
    reg deltaj CCW MSP100 LW10000 lnP, robust
    reg deltaj CCW MSP100 LW10 lnP diffPjPg, robust
```

So far, I have computed the own-price elasticities with the code:

`gen OPE_PLogit=-.4894868*P*(1-Sj)`  for the first model and

`gen OPE_lnPLogit=-1.959741*P*(1-Sj)` for the second model

where `Sj` is the market share of that particular car for that particular year. I do know that in Stata, generally, one computes the elasticity using the `-margins-` command.

Let $k$ be any good but $j$, α be the coefficient on price, η be the price elasticity, Sj be the own-market share, Sg be the share for a particular class of cars, e.g. Sedans, Sk be the share for all cars within a group except car j, and S0 be the overall share for cars other than J. The question is this: given that I have directly specified the regression equation and obtained good regression coefficients, is it still appropriate to use the formula $\eta=\alpha P_j\cdot(1-S_j)$ normally used to compute the own-price elasticity and $\eta=\alpha P_k\cdot S_k $ (.) for the cross-price elasticity if I am using an unbalanced panel dataset? I think I recall my professor saying that an unbalanced panel dataset will adversely affect the elasticities, but I'm not sure how to adjust for this.

Comment: So far, I have computed the own-price elasticities with the code:                               'gen OPE_PLogit=-.4894868*P*(1-Sj)' for the first model and                        'gen OPE_lnPLogit=-1.959741*P*(1-Sj)' for the second model, where Sj is the market share of that particular car for that particular year.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking here: is it just help with the code? That would be off-topic here - have a look at our [help/on-topic]. I have the feeling that underlying this is a statistical issue, but you ought to clarify if your main concern is the mathematics of generating the required elasticities, or the syntax you need for the code?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Questions that are strictly about programming, as @Silverfish mentioned above are off-topic for the site.  If your question is indeed about programming in Stata, [Statalist](http://www.statalist.org/) may be a more appropriate place to post your question.  I can't remember for sure, but I think I have seen questions about generating elasticity matrices on that site (or in the mailing list archives).  Other than that, if you don't need the matrix, but are OK w/ the average elasticities, you can use the built-in `margins` command post-estimation

Comment: Sorry, Silverfish. I do know that, generally, one computes the elasticity using the margins command. The question is this: given that I have directly specified the regression equation and obtained good regression coefficients, is it correct to use the formula η=α*Pj*(1-Sj) to compute the own-price elasticity and η=α*Pk*Sk (where k is any good but j) for the cross-price elasticity in the case of an unbalanced panel dataset? I think I recall my professor saying that an unbalanced panel dataset will adversely affect the elasticities, but I'm not sure how to adjust for this.

Comment: You have added quite a lot of detail in the comments - I think the best thing to do is edit it into the main question. Not all potential answerers will read through the comments! *I recall my professor saying that an unbalanced panel dataset will adversely affect the elasticities, but I'm not sure how to adjust for this* strikes me as a question that ought to be on-topic here, or perhaps at [Economics SE](http://economics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Silverfish, re: the OP's unbalanced panel comment, I think there is a more general statistical concern in there--irrespective of the discipline involved--which has to do with how having an unbalanced panel affects parameter estimates and how to adjust for it, so I don't think it is necessarily off-topic, since the concerns with estimating elasticities on an unbalanced panel (to me at least) are the same with estimating marginal effects or odds ratios for logistic regression, or the $\hat{\beta}$ for linear regression using an unbalanced panel.

Comment: @cembos1005, have you looked at Kenneth Train's *Discrete Choice Methods with Simulation* (2009) for the own and cross elasticity formulae for the logit model?  It is available in its entirety on his [website](http://eml.berkeley.edu/books/choice2.html).  Note, I'm not affiliated with Train, just a huge fan of his work.  Remember that for the logit model, you're now looking at changes in the probability of use instead of the standard "quantity demanded" interpretation for elasticity.

Comment: Thanks marquis! That was exactly my concern. I'm having a look at Train's DCM material--hopefully it'll help!

Comment: @cembos1005, it may be useful to other users of the site for you to include the empirical model estimated (equations are a universal language after all), and briefly explain what $\eta$, $\alpha$, $S_j$, etc. stand for for the users who are not familiar with this notation?